# Understanding the meaning of FNID or // in Fortran code

Tags: fortran

I'm having difficulty understanding the first line of code here:

```
      open(99,FILE=trim(FNID)//'.dat')
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Cycle no: '
  write (99, '(I10)',advance='yes')NCYCLE
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='yes')' '
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Fragment'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Mat-ID'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Part'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Index'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'X-POS'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Y_POS'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Z_POS'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Time'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'X_VEL'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Y_VEL'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Z_VEL'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='no')'Mass'
  write (99, '(A15)',advance='yes')' '
```

As far as I'm aware, the 99 is the valid unit number specifier. Trim  reduces strings to remove padding when printing them. However, I don't know what FNID or // mean in this context.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It joins two strings. We should have a duplicate.

Comment: Is that FNID or //?

Comment: See the duplicate link. FNID is your string. We cannot tell you where it comes from, you must check your code.

Comment: Well, `FNID` is a string, which is presuming a part of a filename.  '//` is the concatenation operator.  So, you're adding the string `.dat` to the non-space portion of `FNID`.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken this open(99,FILE=trim(FNID)//'.dat') line is trying to open a file named FNID.dat which should already exist in the parent directory of the directory the program?

Comment: No, FNID is a string variable in your code. You have to read your code and find where it comes from. Just search for the occurences of  FNID in your code.

Comment: I found it in a module but it has no reference to what it is
CHARACTER (LEN=256):: FNID

Comment: Search for all occurences.